# Two parts in "as" clause

Tags: commas, as

> "This book has put on weight with the passing years, as new chapters
> have been added **and existing** chapters **updated** and expanded to stay
> abreast of changing developments in economies around the world."

I have two questions regarding the passage above,

1. Before "updated", is "have been" removed because it is already used before?
2. There are two subjects in the sentence (new chapters and existing chapters). Don't we add a comma before "and existing"? In my understanding, if there are two subjects, we have to add a comma to connect the two parts by "and".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The writer intends *have been* to work with all three of *added*, *updated*, and *expanded*. I think it would be better to repeat *have been* for the latter two, like this:

> This book has put on weight with the passing years, as new chapters have been added, and existing chapters **have been** updated and expanded, to stay abreast of changing developments in economies around the world."

I agree that commas should be added.